# How to hash GET parameters in url before show in url?

Tags: php, encryption, hash, get

I have simple html form in my website:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    Enter message id<input type="text" name="id">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Encode">
</form>
```

And when I enter id and click to "Encode" button showed my added ID.

How I can show id parameter in hash way to user?

Example functions for encode and decode:

```
<?php

function generate_xor_key($length)
{
    $result = array_fill(0, $length, 0);

    for ($i = 0, $bit = 1; $i < $length; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++, $bit++) {
            $result[$i] |= ($bit % 2) << $j;
        }
    }

    return implode('', array_map('chr', $result));
}

function encode_id($id, $encodedLength = 7, $rawBits = 16, $key = null)
{
    $maxRawBits = $encodedLength * 3;
    if ($rawBits > $maxRawBits) {
        trigger_error('encode_id(): $rawBits must be no more than 3 times greater than $encodedLength');
        return false;
    }

    if ($key === null) {
        $key = generate_xor_key($encodedLength);
    }

    $result = array_fill(0, $encodedLength, 0x30);

    for ($position = 0; $position < $rawBits; $position++) {
        $bit = (($id >> $position) & 0x01) << floor($position / $encodedLength);
        $index = $position % $encodedLength;
        $result[$index] |= $bit;
    }

    do {
        $index = $position % $encodedLength;
        $bit = ($position % 2) << floor($position / $encodedLength);
        $result[$index] |= $bit;
    } while (++$position < $maxRawBits);

    return implode('', array_map('chr', $result)) ^ $key;
}

function decode_id($id, $encodedLength = 7, $rawBits = 16, $key = null)
{
    if ($key === null) {
        $key = generate_xor_key($encodedLength);
    }

    $bytes = array_map(
        'ord',
        str_split(
            str_pad($id, $encodedLength, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) ^ $key,
            1
        )
    );

    $result = 0;

    for ($position = 0; $position < $rawBits; $position++) {
        $index = $position % $encodedLength;
        $bit = (($bytes[$index] >> floor($position / $encodedLength)) & 0x01) << $position;
        $result |= $bit;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

When I enter number "1" to field encode result will be `4256565`
And in url will be `http://hash.loc/?id=1&submit=Encode`

And how I can encode url and show url in example way: `http://hash.loc/?id=4256565&submit=Encode`

Comment: Are you trying to send the encoded value to the server, so the real id is never a part of the request / response?

Comment: And asking to fill `id` is not-a-good-idea-at-all

Comment: You cannot call the php function like that.

Comment: Have you tried to use the submit attribute ,it's the html pendant of onSubmit event, and called the php function via ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Your only choice with the current setup would be creating a redirect PHP-side once the submitted ID has been encoded.

In order to develop a one-shot solution, you have two options:

- implementing a JavaScript AJAX framework that, on form submit: sends the current field value, retrieves the encoded field value and finalizes the submission with the properly formatted ID;
- implementing the ID encoding algorithm on JavaScript side.

With the former approach, it will be just a matter of time before someone discovers and reverses your encoding algorithm... and in the best case scenario a malicious user can run the script as many times as possible in order to obtain a Plain_ID/Encoded_ID lookup table. With the latter approach, your algorithm is publicly exposed to everyone capable of reading JavaScript code.

Converting the GET request to a POST request will hide form data from the browser URL bar... but, nowadays, sniffing POST data being sent by requests is a joke.

In conclusion, no matter what you do... this script will be completely unsafe. And the reason is that the implementation is flawed: you should handle identities through a solid authentication system... not through a form.

Comment: Why submitting the ID in the first place? On creation of the message you generate an encoded id, and you communicate using that encoded id only.